# ThisAddin.Ribbon (Excel) is always null since installing VS2010 SP1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, vsto

I recently installed VS2010 SP1 and now the ThisAddIn.Ribbon value is always null (Excel VStO application addin, using Excel 2010).  No code changes (only change besides VS2010 SP1 was adding the 'TargetFramework' to the GenerateOfficeAddInManifest class -- I guess a new addition in SP1).

When I run my addin and look in the debugger I see that AddIn.Ribbon is null and never gets initialized.  Of course this worked perfectly fine yesterday, prior to my SP1 upgrade.

Did SP1 break Excel application addins that use the ribbon?  Does anyone else have a repro also or a scenario where ThisAddIn.Ribbon is getting initialized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there may have been an (inadvertent) breaking change in Visual Studio 2010 SP1. It seems that the config file is not loaded properly.

You might be able to work around the issue using the tip here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/vsto/thread/0005ca8d-979d-4393-82ff-13a41e788166

Comment: Also, check the registry entries for the path to the Manifest - it needs to be preceeded with file:///

Answer (score 0):

ThisAddIn.Ribbon property does not exist in Excel 2010 Add-in using VS2010.
To access your Ribbon class you need to get it from this collection Globals.Ribbons, e.g.access a custom Ribbon named Ribbon1:

Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1

Check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772088.aspx